# Purpose of the expression (var, var)

Tags: c

I've come across this expression
`((void)(obj), (size_t)0)`

What purpose does this expression (that looks like half a function signature) serve here?

[It's part of a list of macros I found](https://github.com/HerculesWS/Hercules/blob/stable/src/common/ers.h):

```
#define ers_alloc(obj,type) ((void)(obj), (type *)aMalloc(sizeof(type)))
#define ers_free(obj,entry) ((void)(obj), aFree(entry))
#define ers_entry_size(obj) ((void)(obj), (size_t)0)
#define ers_destroy(obj) ((void)(obj), (void)0)
#define ers_chunk_size(obj,size) ((void)(obj), (void)(size), (size_t)0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These macros exist to allow the same code to compile in two configurations. If the controlling macro `DISABLE_ERS` is not defined, then `ers_entry_size(some_o)` will expand to this:

```
((some_o)->entry_size(some_o))
```

Everywhere `ers_entry_size(some_o)` is used in code. But the same code has to build successfully even when we define `DISABLE_ERS`. Those macros could thoretically be defined as

```
#define ers_alloc(obj,type) ((type *)aMalloc(sizeof(type)))
#define ers_free(obj,entry) (aFree(entry))
#define ers_entry_size(obj) ((size_t)0)
#define ers_destroy(obj) (void)0)
#define ers_chunk_size(obj,size) ((size_t)0)
```

But what if `ers_entry_size(some_o)` was the *only way* that a particular function used `some_o`? If the macro expands to `((size_t)0)`, now `some_o` becomes unused. Modern compilers emit warnings about unsed variables. We can't have our code compile to a bunch of warnings in a valid configuration of the library. That's bad library design.

So instead of the naive "no-op" definition, a smarter one is used. Since the [comma operator evaluates each operand and discards all but the last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do), we can leverage it. When the macro is defined like you noted, `ers_entry_size(some_o)` will expand to

```
((void)(some_o), (size_t)0)
```

The first expression fed to the comma operator evaluates and discards `some_o`. It's being *used* now, so there is no warning. The second expression evaluates to the constant, and is the value of the whole parenthesized expression.